# Solving a cubic with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

I am not an expert of complex numbers, and in a (non-English) wiki article I found what seems a very simple way of solving a cubic when $\Delta ( {\tfrac {q^{2}}{4}}+{\tfrac {p^{3}}{27}}) <0: $
($
 y=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}+i\sqrt{-\Delta}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}- i\sqrt{-\Delta}} $) :

$$1) y_1=u_1+v_1=2\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}\cdot\cos\frac{\theta}{3} $$
$$ 2)  y_{2}=u_{2}+v_{3}=2{\sqrt {-{\frac {p}{3}}}}\cdot \cos {\frac {\theta +2\pi }{3}} $$
$$3) y_{3}=u_{3}+v_{2}=2{\sqrt {-{\frac {p}{3}}}}\cdot \cos {\frac {\theta +4\pi }{3}}  $$

If someone can provide a simple way for determining the angle $\theta$, considering for example the cubic:
$$x^3-15x-4=0$$ it would be almost magical to multiply $2\sqrt{5}$ by its ($1/3$,… etc) cosine and find the three solutions in a nanosecond.

Can you explain or refer me to a link where such procedure is explained?

Can anyone tell howthe angle $\theta$ is representedand derived on the complex plane from $p,q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the information from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots), it's easy. So, assuming that $\Delta<0$, the roots of the equation $x^3+px+q=0$ are$$2\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arccos\left(\frac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{-3}p}\right)-\frac{2\pi k}3\right),$$with $k\in\{0,1,2\}$. In your specific case, $\frac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{-3}p}=\frac2{5\sqrt5}$ and therefore the roots are$$2\sqrt5\cos\left(\frac13\arccos\left(\frac2{5\sqrt5}\right)-\frac{2\pi k}3\right),$$again with $k\in\{0,1,2\}$. This is equal to $4$, $-2+\sqrt3$, and $-2-\sqrt3$ respectively.

Comment: @user157860 I could, but it would not be better than the one given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots) (since I wrote it).

Comment: @user157860 It is VIeta's procedure cast in modern language.

Comment: @user157860 No, I don't mean complex numbers. Vieta avoided them completely.

Comment: @user157860 Yes.